# '1 new hat' notification doesn't go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

No matter how often I click the Winter Bash inbox, my `[1]` new hat indicator won't go away. This behaviour started when the inbox told me "You earned the right to run fast and jump for joy on Winter Bash!", so it might be related to that item.

Comment: I have a screencast but forgot where I left the script to convert those into a GIF which can be embedded. Too tired to figure out from which [su] post I copied it ...

Comment: Seems to have something to do with *You earned the right to run fast and jump for joy on Winter Bash!* which is persistently yellow.

Comment: It is related to the [Hat Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwFMq.jpg) - which won't work with Touchscreen @Yaakov + C@ija

Comment: @Glorfindel How about now?

Comment: @AdamLear Not actually completed. I'm still being spammed with the notification, even after refreshing my browser window. Has the build not rolled out to production yet?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog It has. Have you tried refreshing harder? :) I can't repro it now, might have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: @AdamLear Nope, still able to reproduce, after clicking the dropdown, clicking on the item, going back, and refreshing. It just refuses to go away.

Comment: @AdamLear Refreshing for me worsens the problem. If I click on the notification, the [1] dissapears, then when I refresh it appears again :)

Comment: @AdamLear nope, the problem still persists.

Comment: Looks like it is related to running fast and jumping for joy... so I'm now in the same boat as the rest of y'all. We'll have this fixed up in the morning.

Comment: @AdamLear The Touchscreen, instead of requiring spacebar, works - not particularly playable or exciting; but it is what it is.  miss knitting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new hat notification for hat dash now will show up as read, once you have read it.

> put on a mask hat
> notification for you
> read it - acknowledged

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround** using [Userscript](https://github.com/SmartManoj/smart-user-scripts/blob/master/Winter_Bash_2020_Bug.user.js)