# Winter Bash notification glitch

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Every time I go on a site, I receive a Winter Bash notification. But it was just the same notification, over and over again. Even though it only happened yesterday, I’m still wondering why:

1. The same notification reminds me, and
2. The notification appeared after getting 1 hat (my first hat).

Any clarification is greatly accepted.

Edit: In case people viewing this are confused, the “Jump for Joy” notification appears to be the problem, not earning hats.

Comment: This was fixed yesterday... has it come back?

Comment: Yes, but on my computer only

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['1 new hat' notification doesn't go away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357921/1-new-hat-notification-doesnt-go-away)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, the answer over there doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you @KTrain5369? Looking at your inbox right now, the item is showing as being read, and your unread count should be accurate

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now, but is there a way to prevent this in the future?